# Change Button IsEnable via variable UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, isenabled

How can I change the state of `IsEnabled` from a button?
It works with textblocks but not with buttons.

```
bool test1;

if (test1 = true)
{
    //change IsEnabled from button1 to true
}
```

XAML

```
<Button Content="button1" Margin="10,49,0,0"  Click="Button_Click" IsEnabled="False"/>
```

Comment: TBH, bindings should be in place and used here; keep your view and the logic separate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing the button's content with the button's name. The `Content` property contains the text that will be displayed inside the button. What you need to do is to declare the name of the button as well, like this:

```
<Button x:Name="button1" Content="My Button" Click="Button_Click" IsEnabled="False"/>
```

Now you can use the button's name to access it in code:

```
if (test1 == true)
{
    button1.IsEnabled = true;
}
```